# Java concurency - thread pool- multiple requests and users

Tags: java, multithreading, timeout, threadpool, blockingqueue

I am trying to solve the task connected with Java multithreading.
I have thought about using threads pool with blocking queue but I'm not sure whether it will be sufficient in my case.

the problem is that the number of requests must be limited

From what I understood thread pool should do fine in this example but what about the blocking queue?
Don't you think there must be a better solution?

I have thought about using priority blocking queue to give the most active users lower priority but then the priority connected with waiting time (older requests should have bigger priority) should be also updated constantly- this will end in constant queue reorder.

Are there any defined solutions for such a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using a Semaphore. Each incoming request would try to acquire a lock with timeout, then you can be sure that if acquiring a lock succeeds the request is instantly being processed. How's that sound?

Semaphore documentation:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html

I would use just one Semaphore, so the number of permits in the semaphore would effectively equal to max number of connections allowed in the system.

As to the number of connection per user I would keep user connections counters in a ConcurrentHashMap in the semaphore implementation, then customise

```
public boolean tryAcquire(long timeout, TimeUnit unit, Long userId)
    throws InterruptedException {
    AtomicLong connCount = userConnetctionMap.contains(userId) ? userConnetctionMap.get(userId) :  userConnetctionMap.put(userId, new AtomicLong(0));
    if (connCount.get() < MAX_USER_CONN_COUNT) {
        boolean locked = super.tryAcquire(timeout, unit);
        if (locked) {
            userConnetctionMap.get(userId).incrementAndGet();
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

to increment the count per user id if his number of conn is less than max allowed

and custom action:

```
releaseUSerConnection(userId)
```

would decrement that counter

Comment: Could I use many semaphores? One for each of the users- because the number of requests in the system for each user is limited + one to limit the sum of requests and one to limit the number of users inside? Then each request would have to go through all of them within the specified waiting time

Comment: that sounds good but shouldn't I actually override doAcquireSharedNanos in AbstractQuededSynchronizer? Because this is the place where actually acquiring happens and time is down-counted. If I add the condition about maxPerUser in tryAcquire before calling of  doAcquireSharedNanos  and the condition will be false, the countdown will not even happen

Comment: no, doAcquireSharedNanos is private - see my update above

Comment: alternatively, to have more strict control, you could implement that logic in the semaphore critical section after the lock is aquired but this way is more efficient I think

Comment: perfect :> but how to get syn if it is private too?

Comment: what do you mean? what is private too?

Comment: Semaphore has inside private Sync so methods (for instance  sync.tryAcquireSharedNano)  from sync cannot be called from classes extending Semaphore

Comment: yeah but you don't need to touch those, stick to the public methods as in my example

Comment: yeaa actually I'm talking about your solution, exacly this line:         boolean locked = sync.tryAcquireSharedNanos(1, unit.toNanos(timeout)); 
I have tried to write program based on it but I get an error saying sync has private access in Semaphore

Comment: I have tried to finish the task but I get nullpointer exceptions, do you have any idea how to deal with it? sorry for my lack of knowledge but I'm just starting - I have updated the question

Comment: you can release only if you succeeded acquiring a lock, so you need to wrap it with a condition of boolean returned by tryacquire call

Comment: yeah right, but it does not solve the nulls problem. I have also tried changing hashMap to hashTable because hashmap is not synchronized but in vain

Comment: use ConcurrentHashMap instead of hashTable more efficient, where do you get NPE exactly?

Comment: declare userConnectionsMap as volatile

Comment: that's because you're removing an entry userConnectionsMap.remove(userId); while other threads assumed it's there, try decrementing instead

Comment: there are other issues you'll run into, you need to carefully analyse the code